# element not interactable Selenium Python

Tags: парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup, selenium-webdriver

[image: Кнопка Continue to Payment]

Есть код на Selenium, который исправно работает в оконном режиме, нажимает на все необходимые мне кнопки, но если включить режим --headless, то код не может нажать эту синюю кнопку на скрине. Вся странность ситуации в том что он ее видит, я это проверил тем что вывел эту кнопку в лог `print('continue_pay,continue_pay.get_attribute("outerHTML"))`,
он выводит `<button type="button" class="qV80oahDZsbXiS6lIDLND DialogButton _DialogLayout Primary Focusable" tabindex="0">Continue to payment</button>`, но нажать не может, я не понимаю почему.

Я пробовал скролить на этого элемента - `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", continue_pay)`

Я пробовал переключаться между фреймами - `driver.switch_to.frame(continue_pay)`

Я пробовал все виды ожидания - неявное `driver.implicitly_wait(5)`, явное `WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until` и даже `time.sleep()`

Пробовал расширять экран `driver.maximize_window()` и добавлять разные параметры в options

Пробовал взаимодествовать с другим обьектом перед тем как нажать на этот

Пробовал нажать в любую точку на экране, а потом нажать на эту кнопку

Но все время одна и та же ошибка  -

```
Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=122.0.6261.112)
```

При том, еще раз повторюсь, это просходит именно в `--headless` режиме, в обычном оконном режиме все работает